# XML into HTML table for a leaflet map marker popup

Tags: javascript, xml, web, mapping, leaflet

I have a web map with a series of locations (Local Government Area centroids) which are filtered out my map depending on if the LGA has a feature inside or not. It achieves this via an xml document that stores the features that relate to these locations.

```
<LGA name="ThisLGA">
      <feature>
           <name>Feature 1</name>
           <status>lolcat</status>
      </feature>
      <feature>
           <name>Feature 2</name>
           <status>lolcat</status>
      </feature>
</LGA>
<LGA name="ThisOtherLGA">
      <feature>
           <name>Feature 1</name>
           <status>lolcat</status>
      </feature>
      <feature>
           <name>Feature 1</name>
           <status>lolcat</status>
      </feature>
</LGA>
```

What I am trying to do now is have the popup for each LGA marker contain a table with each feature name and status (and possibly other attributes eventually).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this, I saw some people using underscore.js and creating HTML templates. However I do not know how many rows I will need so it has to be done dynamically.

Is it something to be done with php more so than javascript?

Comment: So if I understood you correctly you want to display a dynamic HTML table inside the popup once you click on it?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, thought I'd give the solution if anyone was interested.

Needed a string for the HTML to put into .bindpopup() method.

```
function popupTable(LGA){
//Load in xml document
var xml = loadXML("spatialLayers/nctProperties.xml");
//Start of HTML string for popup
var htmlString = "<div><table>";
//Create list of all LGA nodes
var xmls=xml.getElementsByTagName("LGA");
for (i=0;i<xmls.length;i++){ 
    //Get a specific LGA and create HTML string of
    if (xmls[i].getAttribute("type")===LGA){
        var iteratorLength = xmls[i].getElementsByTagName("name").length;
        //Loop through all child nodes of the LGA
        for (j=0;j<iteratorLength;j++){
            var status = xmls[i].getElementsByTagName("status")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
//Customise icon in table based upon property status
            if (status === "Covenant Registered"){
                var addToString = "<tr><td>"+ xmls[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td><image src=images/mapMarkers/marker1_green_mini.png></td></tr>";
            }else if (status === "Yellow Box"){
                var addToString = "<tr><td>"+ xmls[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td><image src=images/mapMarkers/marker1_yellowbox_mini.png></td></tr>";
            }else if (status === "For Sale"){
                var addToString = "<tr><td>"+ xmls[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td><image src=images/mapMarkers/marker1_brown_mini.png></td></tr>";
            }else{
                var addToString = "<tr><td>"+ xmls[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>";
            }

            //console.log(addToString); 
            htmlString = htmlString + addToString;
    };
    };

};
return htmlString +"</table></div>";
```

}